# Visual Studio Intellisense not recognising class member in bracket initialisation

Tags: c++, arrays, class, intellisense

At first I thought this might be a language limitation of C++, but this actually compiles, it's just that Intellisense doesn't recognise the class members for some reason:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int member;
};

MyStruct staticObj;

int main()
{
    MyStruct localObj;
    int arr1[] = { 1, 2, localObj.member };      // When typing localObj Intellisense says it has no members
    int arr2[] = { 1, 2, staticObj.member };     // When typing staticObj Intellisense says it has no members

}
```

I thought that the fact that C++ doesn't support variable length arrays might be the explanation, but this is a compile-time-known array length, just that its value isn't known. Is this a bug I'm having? Also it compiles fine on Ideone.com

Comment: Does it actually compile when you try to compile it?

Comment: Intellisense is great but it isn't perfect. It is also distinct from the compiler. Sometimes Intellisense fails to deliver but that doesn't mean that your code is incorrect.

Comment: You should give your compiler name and version.

Comment: Yes, it does compile. Looks like a Visual Studio bug then.

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously an Intellisense bug.

Intellisense should not be relied upon for verifying the correctness of your code.

Sometimes, unfortunately, that means you have to put up with false-positive red squiggly lines.

Answer (score 2):

> At first I thought this might be a language limitation of C++, but this actually compiles

This program is well formed.

> I thought that the fact that C++ doesn't support variable length arrays might be the explanation, but this is a compile-time-known array length, just that its value isn't known.

Indeed, there is no VLA in the code and VLA has nothing to do with this.

> Is this a bug I'm having?

`MyStruct` does have a member, so if intellisense says otherwise, it seems to be a bug.